# Python: import module from another directory at the same level in project hierarchy

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, path, package

I've seen all sorts of examples and other similar questions, but I can't seem to find an example that exactly matches my scenario.  I feel like a total goon asking this because there are so many similar questions, but I just can't seem to get this working "correctly."  Here is my project:

```
user_management  (package)
        |
        |------- __init__.py
        |
        |------- Modules/
        |           |
        |           |----- __init__.py
        |           |----- LDAPManager.py
        |           |----- PasswordManager.py
        |
        |------- Scripts/
        |           |
        |           |----- __init__.py
        |           |----- CreateUser.py
        |           |----- FindUser.py
```

If I move "CreateUser.py" to the main user_management directory, I can easily use: `"import Modules.LDAPManager"` to import LDAPManager.py --- this works.  What I can't do (which I want to do), is keep CreateUser.py in the Scripts subfolder, and import LDAPManager.py.  I was hoping to accomplish this by using `"import user_management.Modules.LDAPManager.py"`.  This doesn't work.  In short, I can get Python files to easily look deeper in the hierarchy, but I can't get a Python script to reference up one directory and down into another.

Note that I am able to solve my problem using:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
import Modules.LDAPManager as LDAPManager
```

I've heard that this is bad practice and discouraged.

The files in Scripts are intended to be executed directly (is the **init**.py in Scripts even necessary?).  I've read that in this case, I should be executing CreateUser.py with the -m flag.  I've tried some variations on this and just can't seem to get CreateUser.py to recognize LDAPManager.py.

Answer (score 90):

> If I move `CreateUser.py` to the main user_management directory, I can
>   easily use: `import Modules.LDAPManager` to import `LDAPManager.py`
>   --- this works.

Please, **don't**. In this way the `LDAPManager` module used by `CreateUser` will **not** be the same as the one imported via other imports. This can create problems when you have some global state in the module or during pickling/unpickling. *Avoid* imports that work only because the module happens to be in the same directory.

When you have a package structure you should either:

- Use relative imports, i.e if the `CreateUser.py` is in `Scripts/`:

  ```
   from ..Modules import LDAPManager
  ```

  Note that this **was** (note the *past* tense) discouraged by [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) only because old versions of python didn't support them very well, but this problem was solved years ago. The *current* version of PEP 8 *does* suggest them as an acceptable alternative to absolute imports. I actually *like* them inside packages.
- Use absolute imports *using the whole package name*(`CreateUser.py` in `Scripts/`):

  ```
   from user_management.Modules import LDAPManager
  ```

In order for the second one to work the package `user_management` should be installed inside the `PYTHONPATH`. During development you can configure the IDE so that this happens, without having to manually add calls to `sys.path.append` anywhere.

Also I find it odd that `Scripts/` is a subpackage. Because in a real installation the `user_management` module would be installed under the `site-packages` found in the `lib/` directory (whichever directory is used to install libraries in your OS), while the scripts should be installed under a `bin/` directory (whichever contains executables for your OS).

In fact I believe `Script/` shouldn't even be under `user_management`. It should be at the same level of `user_management`.
In this way you do *not* have to use `-m`, but you simply have to make sure the package can be found (this again is a matter of configuring the IDE, installing the package correctly or using `PYTHONPATH=. python Scripts/CreateUser.py` to launch the scripts with the correct path).

---

In summary, the hierarchy *I* would use is:

```
user_management  (package)
        |
        |------- __init__.py
        |
        |------- Modules/
        |           |
        |           |----- __init__.py
        |           |----- LDAPManager.py
        |           |----- PasswordManager.py
        |

 Scripts/  (*not* a package)
        |  
        |----- CreateUser.py
        |----- FindUser.py
```

Then the code of `CreateUser.py` and `FindUser.py` should use absolute imports to import the modules:

```
from user_management.Modules import LDAPManager
```

During installation you make sure that `user_management` ends up somewhere in the `PYTHONPATH`, and the scripts inside the directory for executables so that they are able to find the modules. During development you either rely on IDE configuration, or you launch `CreateUser.py` adding the `Scripts/` parent directory to the `PYTHONPATH` (I mean the directory that contains both `user_management` and `Scripts`):

```
PYTHONPATH=/the/parent/directory python Scripts/CreateUser.py
```

Or you can modify the `PYTHONPATH` globally so that you don't have to specify this each time. On unix OSes (linux, Mac OS X etc.) you can modify one of the shell scripts to define the `PYTHONPATH` external variable, on Windows you have to change the environmental variables settings.

---

**Addendum** I believe, if you are using python2, it's better to make sure to avoid implicit relative imports by putting:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

at the top of your modules. In this way `import X` *always* means to import the *toplevel* module `X` and will never try to import the `X.py` file that's in the same directory (if that directory isn't in the `PYTHONPATH`). In this way the *only* way to do a relative import is to use the *explicit* syntax (the `from . import X`), which is better (*explicit is better than implicit*).

This will make sure you never happen to use the "bogus" implicit relative imports, since these would raise an `ImportError` clearly signalling that something is wrong. Otherwise you could use a module that's not what you think it is.

Comment: If you are using relative imports, you should execute `python -m user_management.Scripts.CreateUser`

Comment: Instead of `from ..Modules import LDAPManager`, is it possible to do `from .. import Modules`?

Comment: @dancab no it is not possible

Comment: I have to disagree, straight from PEP8: *Absolute imports are recommended...explicit relative imports are an acceptable alternative*

Answer (score 17):

From Python 2.5 onwards, you can use

```
from ..Modules import LDAPManager
```

The leading period takes you "up" a level in your heirarchy.

See the Python docs on [intra-package references](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) for imports.

Answer (score 7):

In the "root" `__init__.py` you can also do a

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '.')
```

which should make both modules importable.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issues. To solve this, I used `export PYTHONPATH="$PWD"`. However, in this case, you will need to modify imports in your `Scripts` dir depending on the below:

Case 1: If you are in the `user_management` dir, your `scripts` should use this style `from Modules import LDAPManager` to import module.

Case 2: If you are out of the `user_management` 1 level like `main`, your `scripts` should use this style `from user_management.Modules import LDAPManager` to import modules.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
import sys  # noqa
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))  # noqa
```

- `# noqa` for disabling `Pylance` linter from changing the import order.

  - Was very important for me
- Use `__file__` to have an absolute path that start from the current script.
- Other approaches other than the `importlib` one. All does rely on running the script from the root of project.
- relative moduels with `...` works relatively to the `pwd`from where you run the script .....
- using `sys.path` or `importlib` both allow us to make something that run regardless of from where we run it. `sys.path` can be simpler that `importlib`. `importlib` is more appropriate in cases where you need to impoprt modules dynamically and conditionally ... Lazy load ....