# Import result from another script in python

Tags: python, import, parameter-passing

I have a supporting library

```
##lib.py
def bagwords(X):
    XXX
    return data
```

Now in my `abc.py` I'd like to use `lib.py` and `returned data`

```
##abc.py
import lib
lib.bagwords(X)
```

I'm wondering in my `abc.py`, how can I pass variable to `lib.py` and use `return data`?

Comment: Your `bagwords` function doesn't accept any parameters.

Comment: No it does accept parameters, only my typo

Comment: Aside from a second typo (`bagwords` vs `badwords`), it seems that you know how to do this. All the parts are in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
##abc.py
import lib
```

> `data = lib.bagwords(X)`

This above will throw an error because X is not defined, but at least it code demonstrates how to get `data` from the `lib.bagwords()` function.

OK - from the comment (`"No, X is defined in abc.py, my problem is: it'll have error: module lib has no attribute bagwords, i don't know why."`) is known that X is defined in `abc.py`, so there will be no error because of that

One possible reason for the error mentioned in the comment is if there is ANOTHER module named `lib` in the search path and it is found and loaded first. So how to avoid the error?

Rename lib.py to myLibrary.py and use the code:

```
##abc.py
import myLibrary
```

> `data = myLibrary.bagwords(X)`

I have tested that it works, so it should work also for you :) .
Happy coding!

Comment: No, X is defined in abc.py, my problem is: it'll have error: module lib has no attribute bagwords, i don't know why

Comment: Horribly sorry forget to respond!

Answer (score 0):

are lib.py and abc.py in the same directory then create the following empty python file __ init __.py to allow import from this directory.

Change your abc.py file as follow:

```
##abc.py
from lib import bagwords
lib.bagwords(X)
```

PS: please have a look at [Python: import module from another directory at the same level in project hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075884/python-import-module-from-another-directory-at-the-same-level-in-project-hierar)

Comment: I tried this, but it said ImportError: cannot import name 'bagwords'

Comment: do you have created the __ init __.py file? If lib.py is in another path you have to use **from <path>/lib import bagwords**.

Comment: No! I think this is problem. But how should I create? Just empty file only with name?

Comment: In my test the library is loaded from current directory without any ____init____.py file.