# Python 3 - ImportError encountered while importing a package from another directory into Flask app

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv, python-import

I created a flask app with `virtualenv` and it has the structure shown below. I'm trying to import an object from `PackageDirectory/fileA.py` into `FlaskDirectory/app/models.py`.

**The errors:**

In `models.py` I use the following statement: `from ...PackageDirectory.fileA import MyObject`, but it gives the error:`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`. So then I declared PackageDirectory as a sources root, and used `from PackageDirectory.fileA import MyObject`, for which it gave the error: `ImportError: No module named 'PackageDirectory'`

**The directory structure**

```
           ├── FlaskDirectory
           │    ├── app
           │    │   ├── __init__.py
           │    │   ├── models.py
           │    │   └── views.py
           │    ├── flask
           │    │   ├── Include
           │    │   ├── Lib
           │    │   ├── Scripts
           │    │   ├── tcl
           │    │   └── pip-selfcheck.json
           │    ├── config.py
           │    ├── run.py
           │    └── app.py
           │
           ├── PackageDirectory (a python package)
           │    ├── ipynb (also a package)
           │    ├── utils (also a package)
           │    ├── __init__.py
           │    ├── fileA.py
```

**`FlaskDirectory/run.py`:**

```
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**`FlaskDirectory/app/__init__.py`**:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
from . import views
app.config.from_object('config')
```

**`FlaskDirectory/config.py`**:

`DEBUG=True`

The `FlaskDirectory/app.py` file you see there is empty, but I'm unsure if I could delete that or if flask uses it in the background

Comment: I hope below link will help you to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075884/python-import-module-from-another-directory-at-the-same-level-in-project-hierar

Comment: I already read that, not helpful in my case

Answer (score 0):

After adding `PackageDirectory` to PYTHONPATH change import to

```
from fileA import MyObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Concretely, you can do what `@phd` says as follows.

```
import sys,os

path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'PackageDirectory')
sys.path.append(path)

from fileA import obj
```