# python pytest importing modules which import local modules

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following python3 project structure:

```
tests/
    - testsuite_service1/
        - test_main.py
    - testsuite_service2/
        - test_main.py
src/
    - service1/
       - codebase/
           - __init__.py
           - main.py
           - logger.py
           - waiter.py
    - service2/
       - codebase/
           - __init__.py
           - main.py
           - logger.py
           - waiter.py
```

In my tests *(pytest)*, I am importing like so:

`from src.service1.codebase.waiter import check_status`

In order to import a specific function within the service1 module.

Within `waiter.py` in service1 I am importing a function from `logger.py` like so

`from logger import configure_logger`

however, when running the tests, I get the error:

```
Traceback:
tests/test_main/test_main.py:3: in <module>
    from src.service1.codebase.waiter import check_status
src/codebase/waiter.py:8: in <module>
    from logger import configure_logger
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logger'.
```

This occurs when the test runs, it feels like `waiter.py` is **not** looking in its local directory to find `logger.py` but rather may be in some other location?

Changing it to

`from .logger import configure_logger`

does solve the issue but causes issues with the runtime I plan on deploying this into *(single zip of service1 with no parent directory)* and thus gives error `Unable to import module 'main': attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Is it possible to not use the relative import and have my test understand where to find the desired files?

Comment: Have you tried `from src.service1.codebase.logger import configure_logger`?

Comment: Also looks like you are missing a `__init__.py` file in the root level of the package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using pytest with a src layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155464/using-pytest-with-a-src-layer)

Answer (score 7):

Adding `import os, sys; sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))` to `__init__.py` in the codebase/ folder solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Can you please explain why adding thing sys.path makes the imports correct?

Comment: @XavierSilva, it works by adding the package/directory name to your path. As a result, any of the modules within that package can be accessed and imported.

Answer (score 1):

The package `src` should contain the `__init__.py` file at root level to indicate it is a package. Then you can use absolute or relative paths to import from other files. The absolute path would be

```
from src.service1.codebase.logger import configure_logger
```

But your relative path should work to after including the `__init__.py` file.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075884/python-import-module-from-another-directory-at-the-same-level-in-project-hierar) for more info.

Comment: Thanks - However src won't exist in the finalized zip file. essentially, in the end, the only files that will actually be deployed is the /codebase folder contents within each service so it won't know anything about src (or even codebase folder) file path at deployment time this is why it needs to stay `import x from y` if possible - maybe I need to move my tests into their respective service folders?

Comment: You should have included this info in the answer... Anyways, this is likely to be a IDE configuration issue with the python path.