# Python importing from a higher directory in same project

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a issue importing a python file from another directory. Below is my project layout.

```
project/
   include/
     networking/
       ssl.py
     process.py
```

Inside my ssl.py file I am trying to access a function inside process.py

I have tried

```
from include.process import procfunction
```

This returns a error

```
cannot import name 'procfunction' from 'include.process'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: I think I had similar problem before. I have learned that it has to do with where you execute your program. If your working directory is at parent level for example project, and you execute ssl.py, it should be ok. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075884/python-import-module-from-another-directory-at-the-same-level-in-project-hierar) post can help too

Answer (score 1):

When you run a python file and have import statements, it is looking at your current directory of that file. In order to move out 1 directory use '..'

Example - Inside your ssl.py:

```
from ..process import procfunction
```

Comment: Just to add to this, am i correct in saying that each directory needs to contain a __init__.py file so that it is registered as a module, or will this method work irrespective of an init files presence ?

Comment: I was actually looking into this yesterday [Main Difference Between a Python Module and Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package).

To my understanding, the main difference between a module and package is that a module is 1 file, and a package is multiple files in a directory, with a __init__.py

Answer (score -1):

You may need to move back up into your include directory. If you're on a Linux this can be done via

```
import os
os.system("cd ..")
from process import procfunction
```

My apologies if this does not help.