# Importing Modules from another sub-folder which is in main sub-folder in python

Tags: python, module, python-import, importerror, relative-import

Modules are not importing into another file which is another folder, I tried to search for the possible solutions with no luck. Here is my practice file hierarchy level

```
python_practice (parent folder)
|
|--------Modules (sub_folder)
|        |
|        |-----fol_1
|        |     |
|        |     |---file_operations.py
|        |     
|        |-----fol_2   
|        |     |
|        |     |---add.py
|-----app.py
```

I am trying to import "file_operations.py" in "add.py" by using absolute imports `from Modules.fol_1 import file_operations` but when I run the file I am getting error as `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Modules'` , this happens the same for `add.py` file when I tried importing `file_operations.py` into it through absolute importing.

Then I tried importing through relative imports by using the following syntax `from .fol_1 import file_operations`  but I am getting error as `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`  the  same goes for `add.py` when I try to import `file_operations.py`.  But when I import both `add.py` and `file_operations.py`  in `app.py` file they work fine and program runs successfully.

Note : I have installed python in "c" drive and I have `python_practice` folder in "D" drive.

PS : I wrote Both "file_operations.py" & "add.py" as modules.

I came across several answers for this I tried this answer [Python: import module from another directory at the same level in project hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075884/python-import-module-from-another-directory-at-the-same-level-in-project-hierar) by using double dot relative imports but didn't work for me, getting same error as mentioned above. Then I tried by adding the `python_practice`  (parent folder) to `path variables` in python even after trying that the same error is coming for both absolute and relative imports.

Comment: Do note that Python imports _do not navigate directories_. Python imports are only resolved by searching the Python path. `from .X` doesn't mean "look for X in the same folder", it means "append `.X` to the current package name, and them import the module corresponding to that fully qualified dotted name".